# Trying to rewrite the url in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress url like `www.example.com/about` and other url which is a normal site in core php `www.example.com/about.php`
I want to rewrite url structure of WordPress site `www.example.com/about` to `www.example.com/about.php`

```
    RewriteEngine On
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^about.php (.*)       about
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^about\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^login/?$ /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /about.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: can you please provide theunderstanding of your code . What exactly u are trying to do